# Подскажите, какие элементы были использованы

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за элементы были тут использованы, чтобы достить такого эффекта? В смысле: при наведении на "График работы" выпадает вот такая вот рамка с треугольником в верхнем правом углу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вроде похоже **но требуется доработать**

[доработанная версия](https://codepen.io/LenskyUser/pen/rwyNZM?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 130px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.parent~.tooltipe {
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: -200000px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .7s, left .3s;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tooltipe:after {
  content: "";
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  border-right: 20px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
}

.tooltipe:before {
  content: "";
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid transparent;
  border-right: 18px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 1px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.parent:hover ~.tooltipe {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="parent" tabindex="-1">
  <span>График работы<span>
  <div class="tooltipe">
   <p><b>Пн-Во</b>:<b>09:00-20:00</b></p>
   <p><i>Обед</i>:<i>13:00 - 14:00</i></p>
  </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Треуголник с псевдо **:before** с

```
border-right transparent
border-left transparent
border-top #f1f1f1
```

А рамка показывается при **: hover**

Comment: спасибо, но тут скорее сложность в треугольнике который указывает носиком на текст "График работы". Как вот его задать...

Comment: Это даст треугольник, но не такой как на картинке, там у него вершина закругленная

Comment: Тогда просто пнг и вопрос закрыт, не?